How to calculate motor flux in Webers from back emf of PMSM Motor and calculate torque in Nm
I have a PMSM motor , unfortunately not much is known about the motor and I am trying to determine some critical motor parameters, one of them is the motor flux in Webers and consequently I am also trying to calculate the torque generated in (Nm).
I read that the motor flux can be calculated from the back EMF, I am a little confused with the units to be used.
After physically rotating the motor (with the help of another motor), The back EMF the motor measured on an oscilloscope(Phase U w.r.t Phase V) is 12.5 Vrms per 1000 RPM.
How do we back calculate the flux?
I also have a little confusion as to what units of back-emf constant to use V/KRPM or V/rad/s ? and how do we convert V/KRPM to v/rad/s?
Once we know the flux , we can find the torque: T = (3/2) * (ψ * Iq) Where Iq is the quadrature axis current(per unit, pu) and T is the torque in Nm.
I found another alternative way of measuring torque, but not sure this is the correct approach, not sure about the formulas used:
1.First find the Motor torque constant (Kt).(which can be derived from back emf)
2.Then for the rated current, I find the equivalent mechanical torque.(which is nothing but quadrature current * motor torque constant)
The base maximum current of my motor driver can measure is 100 A(peak).

One doubt here I have is the unit of Kt Is it Nm/Arms or Nm/Ap?
